# How to bend and curve shadow in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, shadows

How to make the effect in this image with illustrator?
I want to make this effect where the shadow just appears half-way the rectangle and then bend and grow gradually till the end. It gives a realistic feel to the shape. Also, what is the conventional name of this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is not to use a shadow, but to create a separate shape (probably a duplicate of the shape that you want to have the shadow effect), colour it the colour that you want the shadow to be and then apply a blur to that shape. You can then use envelope > distort to bend it and twist it anyway that you want (or any other distortions that you can apply to shapes for that matter).

I don't think that this effect has an 'official' name, but I've heard it called 'peel off' and 'page curl' because of the effect that it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Because you supplied such a small image, it is very difficult to see exactly what you were looking to achieve.  I think this may be what you're looking for.

**In illustrator go to menu item Effect/Stylize/Feather**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And because it's only an effect..  It is nondestructive.  You can re edit the amount of feather or toggle visibility or remove the effect at anytime**

**You could also achieve similar results and have a little more control with adding opacity masks**